# How to open html file on android

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I just create a html file on my pc. it runs offline perfectly on the computer ( all image can be loaded, all javascript function run )
however , when i copy all folder into my phone (include the html file and the image folder,...) and use chrome app to open it , i can only see the text , no image is loaded,no js function is running

I search online and figure out that i may need to work with the Android Studio to create webview for the page , so that i can open the image on phone . however it related to java language which i have no idea to do it .

So is there anyway that i can simply open the html file with full image loaded like on the computer ??

Comment: Does the html file have absolute, or relative references to the image and javascript file?

Comment: check paths of images

Comment: Use relative path of images in your html code and place images properly.

Comment: i use relative reference for the src tag in the html file

Comment: How do you manage to start a html page in Chrome? Chrome will not be in the list for ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: `use chrome app to open it , i can only see the text , no image is loaded,`. If you use normal relative paths in 'src' Chrome will display images too.

Comment: yes but it not working , my relative path is sth like src="img/picture.png" and i put both the ".html file" and the "img folder" in the same folder. it works on computer but not work on android

Comment: So you are not going to answer my question. I wonder why.

Comment: well i click at the html file and choose open with chrome, it opens. i also try another browser and it can be opened too, however , none of them display image